# Does anyone have use for a view count feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, one can sort questions by view count by running a [query on the SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/law/revision/851291/1051136/most-viewed). However, it would be nice to be able to see the results in a format that parallels that for our [Greatest Hits page](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), which provides more information about each entry.

Does anyone know of a greatest-hits-styled page for views, or if there isn't one, would anyone have use for something like that?

A divergence between view count and more traditional markers of question activity (votes, posts, etc.) seems like it might tells us something not only about the question, but also about the viewing audience.

Comment: I agree that could be useful.  But [it was long-ago proposed and rejected on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113042/241697) :(.  You might at least register an upvote for the suggestion there.

Comment: @feetwet Thanks for finding that! Too bad there wasn't much interest. It'd be nice to know if we're drawing a lot of traffic from people who don't plan to register for an account.

Comment: In general I think the answer to that is, "Yes, quite a bit."  Stack Exchange sites rank high on search results.